# liquibase drop table logic

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I deleted a MySQL table name "user" by adding a DROP sentence in Liquibase.
Wonder how would Liquibase react to that in lower level.
Will it first create the "user" table and then drop it? Or it will just ignore the first create table sentence?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase does not have any logic which "optimizes" the changeSets, it just executes the code you've written.

If you have `<createTable>` and then `<dropTable>`, then the table will be created and after that it will be dropped.